# Make: Pattern in target/pattern-specific variable definitions

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile which goes through a build chain, say moduleA.x --> moduleA.y --> moduleA.z, sequentially for many modules A, B, ... I want a variable `var` to take on the value of the module name currently being build, throughout the build chain, for each module. Currently a working solution is to use target-specific variables like this:

```
modules = moduleA moduleB moduleC

moduleA.z: var=moduleA
moduleB.z: var=moduleB
moduleC.z: var=moduleC

all: $(addsuffix .z, $(modules))

$(addsuffix .z, $(modules)): %.z: %.y
    echo $(var)
    # Build .z from .y

$(addsuffix .y, $(modules)): %.y: %.x
    echo $(var)
    # Build .y from .x
```

It is not a very nice solution because I have to repeat the target-specific variable definiton "moduleA.z: var=moduleA" for every module A, B, .... Maybe I could use *pattern*-specific variables instead? I would have guess something like

```
%.z: var=%
```

When I try anything like this, however, the % on the right is interpreted as a literal percent sign.

**Edit**
My example above is not quite complete. Simply using `$*` or `$(basename $@)` in the rules is not a solution, because my modules are really not independent. That is, I could have an extra dependency like this:

```
moduleA.z: moduleB.y
```

When I now `make all` in the case where only moduleB.x has changed, both moduleB.z *and* moduleA.z will be build, like this: First moduleA.z will be build through the chain moduleB.x --> moduleB.y, moduleA.y + moduleB.y --> moduleA.z. Then moduleB.z will be build through moduleB.y --> moduleB.z. Now the `var` variable should be set to "moduleA" throughout the first build chain, but in the very first step, moduleB.x --> moduleB.y, using `$*` or `$(basename $@)` will give me "moduleB" in stead.

Comment: Is simply `echo $*` acceptable? That is, if the variable is always equivalent to the basename, you don't need a separate variable at all.

Comment: Using `$*` is not acceptable. Please see the edit.

Comment: Are you saying that `moduleA` should take precedence over `moduleB` in general? This is starting to look like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). How do you use `var`?

Comment: No, `moduleA` should not take precedence in general. But, following my example, if I do `make all` or even `make moduleA.z`, the `var` variable will be set to "moduleB" during the very first step in building moduleA.z (which is moduleB.x --> moduleB.y). For later steps, `var` will take on the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution is taken from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40974694/make-set-variable-depending-on-which-target-is-to-be-build):

```
$(foreach module,$(modules),$(eval $(module).z: var = $(module)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding, you want `$(var)`, per `%.y`, `%.z` target, to be
the basename of the target. If I complete your makefile like:

```
modules = moduleA moduleB moduleC

moduleA.z: var=moduleA
moduleB.z: var=moduleB
moduleC.z: var=moduleC

%.x:
    touch $@

all: $(addsuffix .z, $(modules))

$(addsuffix .z, $(modules)): %.z: %.y
    echo $(var)
    # Build .z from .y

$(addsuffix .y, $(modules)): %.y: %.x
    echo $(var)
    # Build .y from .x

clean:
    rm -f *.x
```

then from clean the output is:

```
touch moduleA.x
echo moduleA
moduleA
# Build .y from .x
echo moduleA
moduleA
# Build .z from .y
touch moduleB.x
echo moduleB
moduleB
# Build .y from .x
echo moduleB
moduleB
# Build .z from .y
touch moduleC.x
echo moduleC
moduleC
# Build .y from .x
echo moduleC
moduleC
# Build .z from .y
```

In that case, you can dispense with the `var` assignments like:

```
modules = moduleA moduleB moduleC

%.x:
    touch $@

all: $(addsuffix .z, $(modules))

$(addsuffix .z, $(modules)): %.z: %.y
    echo $(basename $@)
    # Build .z from .y

$(addsuffix .y, $(modules)): %.y: %.x
    echo $(basename $@)
    # Build .y from .x

clean:
    rm -f *.x
```