# Make: Set variable depending on which target is to be build

Tags: makefile, build, compilation, gnu-make

In (GNU) make, I want a variable to be assigned a value when the build chain of specific targets are starting. For targets `a.so` and `b.so`, each depending on `b.o`, I can do this manually like this:

```
# Rules
all: a.so b.so
a.so: b.o
    @echo Current .so is $(current)
    touch $@
b.so: b.o
    @echo Current .so is $(current)
    touch $@
b.o:
    @echo Current .so is $(current)
    touch $@

# Set the "current" variable based on which .so is being build
a.so: current = a.so
b.so: current = b.so
```

Here, `current` has the value `a.so` when executing the rules for both `a.so` and `b.o`, while `current` has the value `b.so` only when executing the rule for `b.so`. This is what I want. The mental model I have of this is that the line `a.so: current = a.so` gets triggered as soon as make finds out that `a.so` should be build (that is, before the rules of either `a.so` or `b.so` are run). Please correct me if I'm wrong.

In my actual case, I have many more `.so` files, and so I want to replace the two last lines with something like this;

```
%.so: current = $@
```

or this;

```
sofiles = a b
$(addsuffix .so, $(sofiles)): current = $@
```

However, both of these result in the same, wrong behavior, where the `current` variable gets set anew even when the `b.o` target is about to be build. Why does the `b.o` target trigger these lines? How can I achieve the same behavior as when manually writing `a.so: current = a.so` for every `.so`, but without actually wiring this for every single `.so`?

**Note**: I know that the use case shown in the example code is weird and that the sought after effect can be achieved without this awkward `current` variable. I am however not interested in any solution which solves the problem without using this variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things to discuss here.  First, your mental model of how target-specific variables works is not quite accurate ("the line a.so: current = a.so gets triggered as soon as make finds out that a.so should be build").  What really happens is that each target make encounters creates a new "scope" which is active while that target and all its prerequisites are being created, and the target-specific variables for that target are in effect inside that scope.  Once that scope exits (the target is finished) then those variable settings are gone.

In your example above, `current` will have the value `a.so` inside the recipe for `b.o` *only* when `b.o` is being created as a prerequisite of `a.so`.  If `b.o` was being created as a prerequisite of `b.so`, then `current` would be `b.so`.  Because your makefile lists `a.so` first it will be built first, and because `b.o` will only be built once (per invocation of make), it may appear that it's always using `a.so` as the value of `current` but that's not precisely accurate.  Consider this:

```
$ make all
Current .so is a.so
touch b.o
Current .so is a.so
touch a.so
Current .so is b.so
touch b.so
```

But also this:

```
$ rm -f b.o
$ make b.so
Current .so is b.so
touch b.o
Current .so is b.so
touch b.so
```

See how `current` is set to `b.so` if `b.o` is built because it's a prerequisite of `b.so` not `a.so`.

And also this:

```
$ rm -f b.o
$ make b.o
Current .so is
touch b.o
```

Here because `b.o` isn't a prerequisite of any `.so`, then `current` is not set at all!

The next thing to think about is this line:

```
%.so : current = $@
```

It's not true that this line is "triggered" for `b.o`.  However, this sets the pattern-specific variable `current` to the value `$@` (note, *NOT* to the expansion of the `$@` variable!).  This means that each time `$(current)` is expanded it will expand to `$@`, which is the *current* target name, for whatever recipe it's used in.  So this won't expand to `a.so` or `b.so` unless the current target name is actually `a.so` or `b.so`.  If the target name is `b.o` then `$@` expands to `b.o`.

If you want to do this you can't use a variable like `$@`, you have to use the real value.  You can do this with `eval`, for example:

```
sofiles = a b
$(foreach SO,$(sofiles),$(eval $(SO).so: current = $(SO).so))
```

However, based on the first comments above I'm not sure that's sufficient for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Yes, `current` only gets set when a `.so` file is being build (or some other file is being build as a prerequisite of a `.so` file). This is the intention. Also, using `eval` (to sort of force a variable expansion to take place immediately, right?) works flawlessly!

Comment: `eval` evaluates its argument as if it were a part of a makefile, almost like an inline included file.  See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Eval-Function.html